# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' in array.includes()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm receiving a Typescript error,

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'string & number'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type
> 'string'. 112

```
setProductPrices(productPrices.filter(
  (p): boolean => !selectedProductIds.includes(p.id)));
                                               ^^^^
```

from the following code:

```
export interface IProductPrice {
    id: number;
}
const [productPrices, setProductPrices] = useState<IProductPrice[]>([]);
const [selectedProductIds, setSelectedProductIds] = useState<string[] | number[]>([]);

const deleteSelectedProducts = (): void => {
        setProductPrices(productPrices.filter((p): boolean => !selectedProductIds.includes(p.id)));
        setSelectedProductIds([]);
};
```

The `includes()` method is supposedly
expecting a parameter of 'never' while `p.id` is a number. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This might be due to ! on selectedProductIds which can result in it being null. And typescript is throwing error on this never type. Check the same without ! selectedProductIds but just selectedProductIds.

Comment: I get the same error when I remove the ! mark :(

Comment: When I hover over the includes() method in my IDE it says: `(method) Array<T>.includes(searchElement: never, fromIndex: number | undefined): boolean`
That seems really weird to me that 'never' is in there

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### The Problem

When you have a union of arrays of different types, you can't call methods on them.

#### The Reason

You have `string[] | number[]`, and so `.filter` is:

```
  ((filterFunc: (x: string) => boolean) => string[]) 
| ((filterFunc: (x: number) => boolean) => number[])
```

When TS combines those signatures, it's going to union the two `filterFunc` signatures together:

```
  ((x: number) => boolean) 
| ((x: string) => boolean)
```

This is a little unintuitive, but this simplifies to `(x: number & string) => boolean`.  Because if you have a function that take X, or a function that takes Y, the only safe thing to pass is something that is both `X` and `Y`, or `X & Y`.

`number & string` however, is an impossible type, which "simplifies" to `never`.  Hence why the signature is `(x: never) => boolean`.

#### The Fix

Ideally you'd only use `string[]` or `number[]` but not both.  (Just looking at the code, it's a little mysterious why `id` can only be number, but "selected product ids" can be strings, too)

---

But if you do need to support both strings and numbers, the easiest fix here is to use `Array<string | number>` instead of `string[] | number[]`: the single array type doesn't have the issue of trying to union together two `.filter` signatures.

You can either change your state to be of that type:

```
const [selectedProductIds, setSelectedProductIds] = useState<Array<string | number>>([]);
```

This is simple, but has the downside that it will allow arrays of mixed strings and numbers, which may not be desirable.  (e.g. `setSelectProductIds(['0', 1, '2'])`

---

If not, you can temporarily cast to `Array<string | number>`, do the filter, then cast back to `string[] | number[]`.  This is not super clean, but should be safe:

```
setProductPrices(
    (productPrices as Array<string | number>).filter((p): boolean => !selectedProductIds.includes(p.id)) as (string[] | number[])
);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior [PG](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBBATughiAPAZ2HQEsA7AcwD4oAfNTHXUgVwFsAjCdSgbgFgAUIIDGcUoSgAPfAC5YCZFADaARgA0UAEwaAzBoAsAOhWad+jQFYAuvwGjxwKCFnzEKJQCIsHjR-Y+oD2EPGxExCSwXeDcpfEMAM2IAG2AuAApJZGpJQ2A4GGJJCAATNM0ASnLbewkALyiFFGcE5NT0DKypXLgAVTBIdABhSIg08uQkFA9UDyrBIA). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @bob The compiler is being clever there: despite that you've annotated `xs` as `Foo`, it's still typed as `number[]`.  (You can see that if you hover `xs`)  Here's a version that reproduces: [PG](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgQS1gQwE8AKADwGcAuRCqLGMAcwG0BdRAH0TBAFsARtnYBKRAG8AUIhmIsGKCCxJKAOhTps5RAF4AfIgCEhsiIDckgL6TQkWAmRpMufMQBM5arXqNWHbryCwmxiUrJyCkpInogEFIh4hEQAPHQMzFw8-EJYeiLqTlpkugbGprHxab7smYE57BaWQA)

Comment: When I provide the data upfront it is a piece of cake for the compiler to infere the type of course.

Answer (score 3):

For your useState instead of

```
const [selectedProductIds, setSelectedProductIds] = useState<string[] | number[]>([]);
```

Can you try

```
const [selectedProductIds, setSelectedProductIds] = useState< (string|number)[]>([]);
```

instead?

This is because there is probably some missing code where you've set `selectedProductIds` as an array of string. And in your code you've strictly defined it as 1 array and not the other. Maybe the above change fixes that. Kindly confirm.

Comment: You are correct, that does solve the problem I asked about, sadly it caused other errors so I'm still working on it

Comment: I marked Retsam's answer as the solution because it got me where I needed to be, but for anyone with the same issue, Y M's solution above might work for you